# Angular Material - dynamically switch between pre-built themes

Tags: angular, angular-material

How to add a menu which should allow users to select any of the four pre-built themes that comes with Angular Material.

The top bar (right side) of [Angualr Material site](https://material.angular.io/) has such menu where user can choose between the pre-built themes.

How to achieve this. I don't wish to add any custom themes but use only the pre-built themes.

Comment: You could take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io/tree/master/src/app/shared/theme-picker) for angular.material.io and see how they did it?

Comment: as you can see https://github.com/angular/material.angular.io/blob/fd086cb6185a52391c282977297c1e230999b4ee/src/app/shared/style-manager/style-manager.ts, they just load as link[rel="stylesheet"] selected css